# Grafana API post error

Tags: jquery, api, grafana

I am trying to create a dashboard in Grafana through an AJAX post method, hoping to create a dashboard through my website post, but I dont know why I always got `console.log("Client POST Error");`.( fixed - see my comment)

I am using Node.js as my web server.

But I encounter another problem is  "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Should I reconstruct from

website ->  grafana

to

website  -> webserver(reverse proxyserver) -> grafana?

Is that will be a better way?

This is my JavaScript code:

```
var dashboard = {
    "dashboard": {
        "id": null,
        "title": "WebPos",
        "tags": [ "templated" ],
        "timezone": "browser",
        "rows": [
            {
            }
        ],
        "schemaVersion": 6,
        "version": 0
    },
    "overwrite": false
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#post').click(function(){
        console.log("Client Clicked");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://10.3.1.25:3000/api/dashboard/db',
            type:'post',
            dataType:'json',
            data:JSON.stringify(dashboard),
            success: function(data){
                console.log("Client POST Success");
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log("Client POST Error");
                console.log(e);
            },
            beforeSend: setHeader
        });
    }); 
});

function setHeader(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer eyJrIjoiVGJyWTJuS2dyNVV0VG93Z3FqR0IIQ1hYblJVUlpBTEQiLCJuIjoiZWRpIiwiaWQiOjF9');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*');
}
```

Comment: Added the information of the error you get from the `console.log(e)`

Comment: statusText:"SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified"

Comment: I found the problem is 
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*');
shoud be changed to 
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','*');